# Regressing on percentile stata

Tags: regression, stata

Does anyone know if there is a better way to regress on the top 25% richest females? My code first finds the income cut-off for the 25% richest females and then hard-codes the number in the `if` clause in the regression. Is it possible to have the percentile coded in the `if` clause, so that if I change the data set I do not have to check and adjust the hard-coded part?

Here is my code.

```
/*
Predict medical expenditures for the 25 % richest females 
with and without supplementary expenditures
*/

centile(income) if female == 1, centile(25,75)
regress ltotexp suppins phylim actlim totchr age female income if female == 1 & income > 24, vce(robust)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata stores the results of many of its commands in `r()` (and `e()`). See `help r` and  [[U] 18.8 Accessing results calculated by other programs](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf), and note the section at the bottom of many command help files stating what results are stored in `r()`. For example, in the case of `centile`, `help centile` states:

> ```
> centile stores the following in r():
>
> Scalars   
>   r(N)           number of observations
>   r(n_cent)      number of centiles requested
>   r(c_#)         value of # centile
>   r(lb_#)        #-requested centile lower confidence bound
>   r(ub_#)        #-requested centile upper confidence bound
> ```

So one option is (using a system data set):

```
sysuse auto , clear

// using centile
centile price if foreign , centile(25 75)
local pctile = r(c_2)
regress mpg weight if foreign & price > `pctile' , vce(robust)
```

However, a clearer option would be to access the percentiles from `summarize`:

```
sysuse auto , clear

// using summarize
summarize price if foreign , detail
local pctile = r(p75)
regress mpg weight if foreign & price > `pctile' , vce(robust)
```

Storing the result in the `local` macro `pctile` allows you to refer to it later, if desired.

You could even go a step further, and define the percentile cut-off at the beginning of your do-file:

```
local pctilecutoff = 75
sysuse auto , clear

// using summarize
summarize price if foreign , detail
local pctile = r(p`pctilecutoff')
regress mpg weight if foreign & price > `pctile' , vce(robust)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but there is potentially a very small loss of precision entailed in the storage of a saved resultin a local macro. You can avoid that step by calling up the saved result directly with (e.g.) `=r(p75)' ,

Comment: Excellent answer Brendan! Thanks a lot!